# Interrupted apt-get upgrade - Now won't run again

Tags: debian, apt

I recently started an apt-get upgrade on one of our Debian 6 servers.  The downloads were taking forever, so I exited with Ctrl-C, intending to change the to a different mirror server.

However, now when I run apt-get upgrade I just get :

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

This doesn't seem right to me, since the last upgrade wasn't finished.  What can I do re-run the last upgrade?

Thanks

Comment: Did you run apt-get `update` (as indicated in the title) or `upgrade` (which is a very different operation!) ?

Comment: Oops sorry, typo.  I did an update, but it was the upgrade that got interupted, and which I'm dubious about now. (will correct in question)

Answer (score 2):

You are right about it being wrong I should think. Try doing `apt-get -f install` to clean up borked actions and then redo `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`. This will likely get you going again. To explain a bit further:

- The `-f`switch abbreviates `--fix-broken` - the integrated apt-get way of fixing broken dependencies.
- Once the fixing is done, you may still have broken packages, so doing `apt-get purge <package>` will get rid of any such packages.
- Lastly, you might want to do `apt-get autoremove` to remove any unneeded dependencies that have been pulled in by other packages.

That should cover it.

**EDIT:** This has actually been asked lots of times in many places. [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146150/unable-to-fix-broken-packages-with-sudo-apt-get-install-f) details a case with several compounded issues.